# Getting unique value on the base of Role

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have model name Movie which have many-to-many Relation with Actor Table. Actor Table is further many-to-many relation with Celebrity-Role.
My question is i need only unique values on the base of roles Like Actors who's role is Director they show in Movie Table field with Director and only directors should be there and so on.
i share my models please have a look.

```
class CelebrityRole(models.Model):
    CELEBRITY_CHOICES = (
        ('Actor', 'Actor'),
        ('Producer', 'Producer'),
        ('Writer', 'Writer'),
        ('Director', 'Director'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=8, 
           choices=CELEBRITY_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role


class Actor(models.Model):
    GENDER = (
       ('Male', 'Male'),
       ('Female', 'Female'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=0)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='CelebrityGallery/', 
      blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    birth_place = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_married = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(
       'movies.Movie', related_name='movies', blank=True)
    celebrity_role = models.ManyToManyField(CelebrityRole)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Here is my Movie Table

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    released = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    runtime = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    metascore = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
    imdb_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, 
        unique=True, default='tt3032400')
    imdb_rating = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
    imdb_votes = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    budget = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    box_office = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    imdb_original = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    season = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=0, 
          blank=True)
    episode = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=0, 
           blank=True)
    poster_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='Posters/', 
         blank=True)
    video_poster_url = 
    models.ImageField(upload_to='VideoPosters/', blank=True)
    video_url = models.TextField(validators=[URLValidator()], 
          blank=True, max_length=2000)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, 
                  related_name='genre_movies')
    image_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(ImageGallery, 
              blank=True)
    video_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(VideoGallery, 
           blank=True)
    director = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, 
         related_name='director')
    writer = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, 
            related_name='writer')
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, 
         related_name='actors')
    producer = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, 
         related_name='producer')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

[image]

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Please have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can do it in your models.py. But you can use the filter method in your views.py when making queries to filter actors whose role is director, etc.